# Can't drag and drop cells in InDesign table

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

So I've spent way too much time searching on this one. I can't seem to drag and drop the text of one cell to another. I want to move what I have in my table from column 1 into column 2. Simple yet doesn't work no matter what I try.

If I highlight the cell and move it outside the table, I do get the cursor change with the little box at the corner - but it doesn't work. I click on where I want it to go, or try to drag it there, nothing changes. No blue box gets highlighted to show me where I can drag to. Manually copy and pasting the text is my only option at this point but obviously it is not an ideal workflow. HELP!

PS I am just in disbelief at this point - can ID really be this obtuse with its table functions? Take a hint from Excel, Adobe!

Comment: Not sure, but you probably can't do that. Indesign's table functions are limited compared to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the drag and drop text feature for the layout mode ?
http://indesignsecrets.com/drag-and-drop-text-in-layout-view.php